# Saving milon generated barcode in my laravel directory

Tags: php, laravel, barcode

I want to save my generated milon barcode to my laravel directory on server.
I'm using this code in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $total = $request->qty;
      for( $i = 0; $i < $total; $invitation = $i++ ){
        $barcode = $this->code(5);
        $invitation = New Invitation;
        $invitation->reg_no = $barcode;
        $invitation->distributor_id = $request->distributor;
        $invitation->event_id = $request->event;
        $invitation->type = $request->type;
        $invitation->status = 0; //0->blum dipakai
        $invitation->QR = DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath($invitation->reg_no, "QRCODE");
        $invitation->save();
      }

      return redirect()->back()->with('message','cie berhasil masukin data');
    }
```

It turns out that it automatically saved, but not in my public directory, but outside the directory, like this:
[image saved outside public](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbq94.png)

then I tried to put on my last code but nothing happen
 `\Storage::disk('public')->put('test.png',base64_decode(DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath($invitation->reg_no, "QRCODE")));`

is there anything i can do about this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you link your storage into your public/storage ?

Run this command and try saving via Storage:: ..  like you mentioned in your ques.

```
php artisan storage:link
```